# How do I grab a table from a database and display it on a webpage?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, database

I was wondering how I could pull a table from a database I already have set up. I have my own code, but it won't work out. The objective is for the person to click on a button that runs a JavaScript function that runs a PHP file and then displays it on website in a specific div I have for it. If anybody can help me figure out what is wrong that would be awesome! Here is the code:

> Kataajax.js

```
tkakata(){
var xmlHttp = createXmlHttpRequestObject();

function createXmlHttpRequestObject()
{
    var xmlHttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
    {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } 
    else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

    if(!xmlHttp)
        alert("Something went wrong")
    else
        return xmlHttp
}

function process(){
    if(xmlHttp.readyState==0 || xmlHttp.readyState==4)
        {
            xmlHttp.open("GET", "tkakatagrab.php", true)
            xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleServerResponse();
            xmlHttp.send(null);
        }
    else
        {
            setTimeout('process()',1000);
        }
}

function handleServerResponse()
{
    if(xmlHttp.readyState==4)
    {
        if(xmlHttp.status==200)
        {
            xmlResponse = xmlHttp.responseXML;
            xmlDocumentElement = xmlResponse.documentElement;
            message = xmlDocumentElement.firstChild.data;
            document.getElementById("displayrank").innerHTML = message;
            setTimeout('process()',1000);
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Database not connecting!")    
        }
    }
}
}
```

> tkakatagrab.php

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>';

$con = mysqli_connect('IP','username','password','TKACONT');
if(!$con){
die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}


$sql="SELECT Firstname,Lastname,Kata FROM Contestant ORDER BY Kata DESC";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

echo '<response>';
echo "<table>
<tr>
<th>Points</th>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>";
//while loop right here
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Kata'] .  "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Firstname'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Lastname'] .  "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
echo '</response>';

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: What happens with this code? If you're using jQuery I'd recommend using the jQuery AJAX functions. `I have my own code, but it won't work out` doesnt really tell us where the problem lies.

Comment: @chris85 I could be mistaken here, but might it be possible all those echos are causing an issue here? I mean, I'm not sure if PHP will return all at once in a single string or ajax simply only gets the first echo?

Comment: @icecub it will get the full response, it doesn't matter how many time you `echo`.

Comment: Go into your developer tools ( `ctrl` + `schift` + `i` in chrome ) and then watch the network. You will see your request appear, look at the `reponse` box. You are probably going to see an error there.

Comment: @Nytrix Thanks. It kinda confused me a bit. `Echo` is considdered output but appearently it isn't actually send back as a response before the entire response is finished. At least, I think. I'll have to research this a bit more.

Comment: This is a good opportunity to start practicing some debugging techniques.  You have debugging tools in your browser for inspecting the network requests, stepping through the JavaScript code, and looking for client-side errors.  For server-side code, you can check your PHP logs or write useful debugging info to the output during development or even step through in an IDE debugger.  Currently you're just saying "it doesn't work", but you need to determine *how* it "doesn't work" in order for us to meaningfully answer *why*.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I'll get onto debugging it then.